# Using word list to brute force encrypted partition

Tags: encryption, password-recovery

I used the **Disk Utility** to encrypt an external HDD about a month ago. Now it seems that I have forgotten the password. I have formed it according to a set of rules, so I have generated a word list (with a Python script) of ~400,000 candidates. I'm pretty confident that my lost password is somewhere among these, but I don't really feel like trying them all out by hand.

So the question goes: is there any tool which would take my word list a try them *automatically*? Or if not, how should I go about writing a script like that?

I've used a similar tool on GPG earlier, it's called **[nasty](http://www.vanheusden.com/nasty/)**.

(If someone is interested in my extremely simple permutation script, [it can be found on **Pastebin**](http://pastebin.com/1SQSASdU).)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The return value of

```
echo "passphrase" | sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda1 encrypted
```

is:

- 0, if there's a key for this passphrase
- 234, if there's no key for this passphrase

It shouldn't be too hard to write a bash script, that loops over your word list, trying each passphrase and checking the return value.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

DEVICE="/dev/sda1"

if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
   echo "This script must be run as root." 1>&2
   exit 1
fi

while read line; do

    echo "$line" | cryptsetup luksOpen "$DEVICE" encrypted 2>/dev/null

    # success
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
        cryptsetup luksClose encrypted
        echo "Passphrase: $line"
        exit 0
    fi

done < "$1"

echo "Passphrase not contained in word list."
exit 1
```

Save, change device, make executable, run like `sudo ./find-password /path/to/wordlist` and wait.

Note: This is **slow**. I don't know if it's because I tried this on a SD card, but it took five seconds to test four wrong passphrases (almost 6 days for 400,000 possible passphrases).

Update: Seems CPU bound. If you split your word list and do something like

```
(sudo ./find-password words.0 &) ; (sudo ./find-password words.1 &)
```

It will use two cores and almost half the time per try.

Comment: Excellent, seems to work perfectly! Thank you. I suspected that it would be CPU bound since it was as slow on my HDD.